# Is there any way in mountain lion to change copy paste shortcut keys?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard

I am using a mac and I use parallels as i need to use windows as well.  One thing that keeps bugging me is that on windows i use Control+C and on mountain lion i have to use Command+C.

Is there anyway to have Control+C work on mountain lion?  Is there way to change the shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the copy shortcut to be <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, map the physical alt key to control in Windows using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229633/how-to-globally-map-altgr-key-to-alt-key#396859.

If you want the copy shortcut to be <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, change the Control key to be the Command key in OS X in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys..., and then change the Windows key using the same method as above.