# Keyboard shortcuts - make OS X like Windows?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I run Windows 7 at work and OS X at home. 2 sets of muscle memories is a hassle - is there  a way to map all 'Apple +' commands into 'Ctrl +'?

E.g. turn <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) can change key combinations like control+c to command+c everywhere:

[image]

You can add your own settings in [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). See the source for the [keycode constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml?raw=true).

You can change text editing shortcuts by creating a DefaultKeyBinding.dict. See [TextMate Blog » Key bindings for switchers](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/) and [Windows%20Bindings.dict](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/KeyBindings/Windows%20Bindings.dict).

Related questions:

- [Is there any way in mountain lion to change copy paste shortcut keys?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/is-there-any-way-in-mountain-lion-to-change-copy-paste-shortcut-keys)
- [Efficient key bindings using both Mac and Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/426515/efficient-key-bindings-using-both-mac-and-linux)

Comment: According to their GitHub page, "Karabiner is obsoleted on macOS Sierra (10.12) or later. Please use Karabiner-Elements." Link to Karabiner-Elements - https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements